# Magento - Quote item is not found

Tags: javascript, ajax, magento

We have used  paid theme. When we try to add to cart  it is displaying  error message in the cart page :

> Quote item is not found.

we have disable all extension in magento.but same error message  How can we fix it?

Comment: Could you please describe, which theme you are using? Are you working with the Magento sample data or your own products?

Comment: We are using emtheme.we are working own product .we have checked inventory its 10000  but we have change theme rwd its working fine